# Why the user = await User.findOne({ email }) returns null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm setting up a login route and I decided to test it with postman and it worked but later when I was checking my DB configuration I found an error when I fixed the error the login test on postman doesn't work
so in my ***server.js*** file I have :

```
const express = require("express");

const connectDB = require("./config/db");

const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// Initialize middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Define routes
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/users"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/api/posts", require("./routes/posts"));
app.use("/api/profile", require('./routes/profile'));

// Create server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

The connectDB function in ***config/db.js*** :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config()

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        });
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

In the ***auth.js*** route :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { check } = require("express-validator");

const {auth} = require('../middlewares/auth');
const {login} = require('../controllers/authController');
// @route:  POST api/auth
// @desc:   Login
// @access: Public
router.post("/",
    [
        check("email", "Email is required").not().isEmpty(),
        check("password", "Password is required").not().isEmpty(),
    ],
    login
);

module.exports = router;
```

The Auth controller in ***controllers/authController.js*** :

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require('dotenv').config()

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Check for validation errors
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        // Check if user exists
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials : you must register" });
        }

        // If exists, check password
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials : wrong password" });
        }

        // Return jwt
        const payload = {
            user: {
            id: user.id,
            },
        };
        jwt.sign(payload,
            process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn: 3600},(err, token) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.json({ token });
}
        );
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send("There was an error with the server. Try again later.");
        }
}
```

Everything looks great and when I try to login with postman it returns the "Invalid credentials : you must register" message from this code in ***authController.js*** ( when I console.log(user) it returns null ) :

```
const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials : you must register" });
        }
```

PS: At first, in the db configuration I forgot to add the mongo client options and everything worked and it returns the token in postman but after fixing the error I had the login problem

Comment: If it's returning null and not throwing an error, it seems like your db config is probably fine. Are you sure you're querying an email address that exists? Also, try putting your query in a try/catch loop and logging any errors.

Comment: 1 - Can you check if `email` contains the value you are submitting?
2 - Can you check if the database actually contains a document with that email?
3 - Can you check what's the value that `findOne` method returns?

Comment: As I said when I did the database configuration for the first time I forgot to add the mongo client options object { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: trueuseFindAndModify: false  } and everything worked. When I did add the mongo client options that's when I had the null return valueand when I delete the mongo client options everything returnto normal and it works (so I'm sure that the email and password are correct and they are contained in the database)

Comment: email is unique and index? @MedMhamdi

Comment: try this: 
`const user = await User.findOne({ email: email }`.  You need to tell your db what to look for. First is the field, second is the value.